# How to stop calendar event invitation Emails by outlook in Android?

Tags: android, outlook, microsoft-graph-api

We are using [Microsoft graph calendar API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/calendar-post-events?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http) for creating an event in the Microsoft(outlook) calendar. We don't want to send default RSVP mail of calendar event invitations to the user so,
Is there any way to stop this email by using android?

In the Google calendar event, we can stop email notifications by `setSendNotifications(false)` 
i.e.,
`mService.events().insert(calendarId,event).setSendNotifications(false).execute();`

Kindly suggest how can we achieve it?

[image]

[image]

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Outlook Mail REST API: send message with attachment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32198237/outlook-mail-rest-api-send-message-with-attachment)

Comment: @LalremLianBTlung Unfortunately No. We are using `POST https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/calendar/events` API to create an event. Microsoft automatically sends that RSVP email to all invitees to the event. we need to stop that email.